# getSherlockActivity in onPrepareOptionsMenu return null

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

im using ActionBar Sherlock 4.2. I get a null reference in my onPrepareOptionsMenu Method when the user rotates the Device. It happens when switching back from a Dual Fragment Layout in Landscape mode to Protrait Mode which only displays the 'master' fragment without the Detail Fragment. But still my Detail Fragment gets called. First i throught i did something wrong in my menu.xml, but this is simply not the case. The Activity is null returned. Anyone have a tip where what may is wrong there ?

Strange is also that the code passes the isDetached() check.

Any hints appreciated,
Kitesurfer

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.support. v4.view.Menu)
 */
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)
{
    if (getListAdapter() == null || getListAdapter().isEmpty() && isDetached())
    {
        return;
    }


    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.forecast_options_navigate_to_spot);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Menu item size:" + menu.size());
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Activity:" + getSherlockActivity());
```

Output:

```
11-11 13:07:46.862: D/MyFragment(27997): Menu item size:8
11-11 13:07:46.862: D/MyFragment(27997): Activity:null
```

Comment: At the moment i fix this by checking the activity == null. Quite dumb solution but works so far. I checked my FragmentPagerAdapter as i may excepted something gets not detached, but the code gets called after the onPrepareOptionsMenu method.

Answer (score 0):

So, i found what is wrong. In my PagerAdapter i did something stupid.

In my

```
public void onTabUnselected(final Tab tab, final FragmentTransaction nullTransaction)
```

I did a call to getItem() which creates another Fragment, which of course gets detached in this  Method. This causes the Activity to be null in onPrepareOptionsMenu.